# Input multiple answer in SPSS

Tags: input, spss

I've faced some problems regarding how to input data in SPSS when it comes to multiple answers. Let say the question is like this:

**What is the main mode of access to these online courses? (you may choose more than one answer if applicable)**

- Wired campus network
- Wireless campus network
- Mobile broadband
- Wired broadband/ADSL
- Mobile packet data

And the student answers more than one answer. So how can I input all these data in SPSS. This is different from a scaling question where each parameter has a scale. It is only one question, but multiple answer... I really dont know how to find the solutuion. I've been asking many people, refer on books, searching on internet, but all that is not enough and I didn't find any answer until now.

Answer (score 2):

These are sometimes referred to as multiple response sets. You would typically have separate variables (i.e. columns) for each potential answer, and then use some type of integer representation for when a person checked that response and when they did not check that response. Most frequently people use 0 for when they did not check that response and 1 for when they did. Afterwards you can define multiple response sets through a GUI dialog, and this is useful when generating tables.

Googling for multiple response sets SPSS seems to bring up alot of useful resources. I also know [John Hall has posted tutorials](http://spssx-discussion.1045642.n5.nabble.com/Multiple-response-in-SPSS-and-other-methodology-uploads-td1073902.html) for multiple response sets in SPSS that may be useful.